# Add columns to Cross-Tab element

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

Report needs to have a table (like a matrix in SSRS) with dynamically created columns and rows based on data from dataset. With no additional requirements, the crosstab works perfectly. But I need to add static columns outside of any group (horizontal or vertical) which will be shown in any case. I tried to do this with Cross-Tab element in Crystal Reports but without success.

Is it even possible to do such a task using aforementioned element? Is it possible to add new columns to expand cross-tab element?

Currently, on y-axis I show months, on x-axis I show customers, but I need two additional columns, like customer code, or something else.

[image]

In the picture above is presented desired output. Little explanation: **Value from dataset 1 ... n** are generated in runtime, based on data from dataset, while **Date of birth** column is always present.

What I got already is table with dynamically generated **Value from dataset 1 ... n** but I cannot add new column **Date of birth** in Cross-Tab element.

I think it is clear enough now.

Comment: What is the crosstab currently configured to show, and what are you hoping to add to it? These details will be necessary to a potential solution.

Comment: you can add columns using option calculated members but if you need the process provide more info what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: I edited my question now

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it but you will get the extra column at the end not at the beginning as stated in your question.

Go to preview and then go to the last column of cross tab

```
Right click --> calculated member --> insert column
```

After that you can get new column and add the changes you require

Comment: In VIsual Studio, where I added add-on for Crystal Reports, there is no such menu for right-click on preview. By the way, this can be easily done via SSRS, so I thought it needs same efforts for such task, but I was wrong.

Comment: Actually it is easy... I done this many times in CR and I work on CR as a standalone application